# How to install Nokia Pure Fonts for Qt Creator simulator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, nokia, meego

I am develop Meego apps with Qt creator, but the simulator is not rendering with Nokia Pure font, which is the default font for Meego. I searched and could not find a way to install that font. Please help. Thanks!